# Cloud Run Service to Service via GRPC

Tags: grpc, google-cloud-run

I've two cloud run services,  frontend and listservice.  Both are currently open to receive traffic from all/everywhere on the internet. The call to the frontend service using HTTP then calls the listservice via GRPC. I can call both cloud run services via postman but the frontend service cannot connect/call the listservice via GRPC.  I have this working locally. And get this error on the frontend cloud run logs:

Error: 1 CANCELLED: Call cancelled at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

or

Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

I've allowed both services to be publicly accessible:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/public

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Cloud Run logs from the frontend would be helpful. Presumably (since it's not shown), you're calling the backend service via gRPC (HTTP/2) and not REST or HTTP/1? [`gRPCurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) is a great tool and CLI-based making it easier to include its output in questions here.

Comment: yes backend listservice called via gRPC (HTTP/2) is not enabled on back end service, when it is it still does not work. Also postman call to backend service does work.

Comment: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

Comment: end to end from flutter client via http api to frontend and from frontend via grpc to backend locally works as expected. individually each service runs on google app engine (flutter client) and cloud run. Flutter client on app engine can talk to the front end and I can see the request in the frontend log so working as expected. it's the frontend to listservice GRPC that is blocked.

Comment: You're not including sufficient information to help a diagnosis... no logs, code etc. You say that it works locally.... when you deploy to Cloud Run (and assuming you are making the Cloud Run service public) are you connecting to the correct URL and its port 443!?

Comment: sorry about the detail, I'm limited to what I can upload here, can't add files and characters are limited. yes correct url and i've tried port 443 and 8080. by default back end grpc server is listening on 8080 but accepts requests on 443 via postman

Comment: both cloud run services are public, no restrictions. back end grpc server  console.log("Server listening on port :" + config.PORT);

  server.bindAsync(
    //`[::]:${config.PORT}`,
    `0.0.0.0:${config.PORT}`,

    grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),

    () => {
      server.start();
    }
  );

Comment: Cloud Run deploys a proxy along with your container. Your container listens on `PORT` (usually `8080`) but the proxy adds an X509 cert and accepts traffic on 443 proxying to your container's port. Your client will need to use TLS (secure!) to connect to the backend service. You've not added detail to the questions per my suggestion and so I'm unable to provide more help

Comment: thanks for the guidance, using node how do I setup a TLs/secure connection and associated credentials?

Comment: solved it:  const list_proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).list;

credentials = grpc.credentials.createSsl();


service_address = config.SERVICE_ADDRESS+':'+config.SERVICE_ADDRESS_PORT;

const listStub = new list_proto.ListService(service_address,
  credentials);